# Very simple Xamarin application is not displaying an image online

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to display an image through a very basic Xamarin application on Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Test19Oct13.MainPage">
        <StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Source="https://giphy.com/gifs/internet-facebook-zi-l41lX2yEwhnD6QrLi" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

Previously, this was working, but the images no longer show on Android (they show on iOS). My Android Build settings are set so that HttpClient implementation is AndroidClientHandler and SSL/TLS implementation is Native TLS 1.2+ (settings attached here: [androidBuildSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xlh6.png)

Can anyone tell me why the image isn't displaying?

EDIT: I have a colleague who is running version 16.2.5 of Visual Studio and this code works perfectly fine. My code ran on version 16.3 and does not work. I've included a screenshot of his settings: [oldVSsettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68zP1.png)

Answer (score -2):

Create a Custom Renderer for the image control as below,

```
public class CustomImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "IsLoading")
            {
                var handler = Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Registrar.Registered.GetHandlerForObject<IImageSourceHandler>(Element.Source);
                if (!Element.IsLoading && Control != null && Control?.Image == null && handler is ImageLoaderSourceHandler)
                {
                    var imageLoader = Element.Source as UriImageSource;
                    var imgPath = imageLoader.Uri.OriginalString;
                    NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.SharedSession;
                    var task = session.CreateDataTask(new NSUrl(imgPath), (data, response, error) =>
                    {
                        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                Control.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    task.Resume();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is overkill for such a simple application. The Xamarin docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows) do not suggest this sort of solution for simply displaying an image.